# Making input fit td height and width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have included all the popular recommendations in Stack Overflow how to do this, but still my `input` has a bit lower `height` than the `td`.

Looks like the key css options are `display:table-cell;` and `width:100%;`

**IMPORTANT** - If I remove `table table-condensed`, it's OK.

But the question is, how to preserve `input`'s `height` with `table-condensed`?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22307/)

```css
td.zeon_input_table_cell input {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent
}
td {
  border: solid
}
```

```html
<table id="formset" class="form table table-condensed zeon zeon-row-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row1">
      <td class="zeon_input_table_cell">
        <input id="id_form-0-id" name="form-0-id" type="hidden" value="1">
      </td>

      <td class="zeon_input_table_cell">
        <input id="id_form-0-min_delivery_value" name="form-0-min_delivery_value" step="any" type="number" value="5000.0">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap has by default `padding: 5px` value in `table td`, as shown below:

```css
.table-condensed thead > tr > th,
.table-condensed tbody > tr > th,
.table-condensed tfoot > tr > th,
.table-condensed thead > tr > td,
.table-condensed tbody > tr > td,
.table-condensed tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

So you need to override them.

But **NOT USING `!IMPORTANT`** - this is **BAD PRACTICE**

Instead, being **more specific** in your rule.

This is called [CSS specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), you can calculate the specificity of your selector(s) [here](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Also, in your `input` you just need `width:100%`

```css
#formset td.zeon_input_table_cell input {
  width: 100%;
}
#formset td {
  border: solid;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="formset" class="form table table-condensed zeon zeon-row-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row1">
      <td class="zeon_input_table_cell">
        <input id="id_form-0-id" name="form-0-id" type="hidden" value="1">
      </td>

      <td class="zeon_input_table_cell">
        <input id="id_form-0-min_delivery_value" name="form-0-min_delivery_value" step="any" type="number" value="5000.0">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: dippas, your answer looks like the correct one, but I just can't see it work in JSFIddle. Can you please provide it there so that I can tick it as correct ?